# Shipping Price is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

In my view.phtml i have called the estimate shipping price by this:

```
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
```

But when I clicked to get a Quote for shipping nothing works and the price for shipping is not showing .Can anyone help me please. IF I am doing any wrong or something is not enable in backend

Comment: can you show your layout file

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- SHOW SHIPPING RATES-->
        <?php $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('ES'); // Set your default shipping country here
        $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
        $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);
        $quote->addProduct($_product);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
        $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();
        // Find cheapest rate
        $cheapestrate = null;
        foreach ($rates as $rate) {
            if (is_null($cheapestrate) || $rate->getPrice() < $cheapestrate) {
                $cheapestrate = $rate->getPrice();
            }
        }
        $corehelper = Mage::helper('core');
        if ($cheapestrate) {
            echo '<p><strong>Shipping costs:</strong> ' . $corehelper->currency($cheapestrate);?></p>
            <?php
            }else {
            echo "<strong>Free shipping</strong> for this product." ;
        }?>
        <!-- END SHOW SHIPPING RATES-->
```

This only works for Simple products